# Using Swift, how do you re-encode then decode a String like this short script in Python?

Tags: python, swift, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

XKCD has some issues with their API and weird encoding issues.

[Minor encoding issue with xkcd alt texts in chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347929/minor-encoding-issue-with-xkcd-alt-texts-in-chat)

The solution (in Python) is to encode it as latin1 then decode as utf8, but how do I do this in Swift?

Test string:

```
"Be careful\u00e2\u0080\u0094it's breeding season"
```

Expected output:

```
Be careful—it's breeding season
```

Python (from above link):

```
import json
a = '''"Be careful\u00e2\u0080\u0094it's breeding season"'''
print(json.loads(a).encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
```

How is this done in Swift?

```
let strdata = "Be careful\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0094it's breeding season".data(using: .isoLatin1)!
let str = String(data: strdata, encoding: .utf8)
```

That doesn't work!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Swift, so I don't know what to suggest. The Latin1 "trick" works because for 0 <= `n` < 256, Unicode codepoint `n` encodes to the byte with value `n` in Latin1. That is,   `b''.join([chr(i).encode('latin1') for i in range(256)]) == bytes(range(256))` is True.

Comment: What result do you expect for the Swift example?

Comment: @PM2Ring So would that work for this comic for instance? https://xkcd.com/1814/info.0.json

Comment: @MartinR Updated to make it more clear with expected output and a proper string in Swift

Comment: Sure. I get `♫ When the spacing is tight / And the difference is slight / That's a moiré ♫`

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode the JSON data first, then extract the string, and finally “fix” the string. Here is a self-contained example with the JSON from https://xkcd.com/1814/info.0.json:

```
let data = """
    {"month": "3", "num": 1814, "link": "", "year": "2017", "news": "",
    "safe_title": "Color Pattern", "transcript": "",
    "alt": "\\u00e2\\u0099\\u00ab When the spacing is tight / And the difference is slight / That's a moir\\u00c3\\u00a9 \\u00e2\\u0099\\u00ab",
    "img": "https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/color_pattern.png",
    "title": "Color Pattern", "day": "22"}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// Alternatively:
// let url = URL(string: "https://xkcd.com/1814/info.0.json")!
// let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

do {
    if let dict = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any],
        var alt = dict["alt"] as? String {

        // Now try fix the "alt" string
        if let isoData = alt.data(using: .isoLatin1),
            let altFixed = String(data: isoData, encoding: .utf8) {
            alt = altFixed
        }

        print(alt)
        // ♫ When the spacing is tight / And the difference is slight / That's a moiré ♫
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you have just a string of the form

> Be careful\u00e2\u0080\u0094it's breeding season

then you can still use `JSONSerialization` to decode the `\uNNNN`
escape sequences, and then continue as above.

A simple example (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
let strbad = "Be careful\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0094it's breeding season"
let decoded = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data("\"\(strbad)\"".utf8), options: .allowFragments) as! String
let strgood = String(data: decoded.data(using: .isoLatin1)!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(strgood)
// Be careful—it's breeding season
```

---

**Addendum:** Here is a more robust version of “fixing” the wrong JSON encoding. It searches for occurrences of `\uNNNN` in the source string and converts them to bytes, which are then interpreted as UTF-8. The advantage over the previous approach is that other non-ASCII characters in the source string remain untouched:

```
extension String {

    func decodeBrokenJSON() -> String? {

        var bytes = Data()
        var position = startIndex

        while let range = range(of: "\\u", range: position..<endIndex) {
            bytes.append(contentsOf:self[position ..< range.lowerBound].utf8)
            position = range.upperBound
            let hexCode = self[position...].prefix(4)
            guard hexCode.count == 4, let byte = UInt8(hexCode, radix: 16) else {
                return nil // Invalid hex code
            }
            bytes.append(byte)
            position = index(position, offsetBy: hexCode.count)
        }
        bytes.append(contentsOf: self[position ..< endIndex].utf8)
        return String(data: bytes, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print("Be careful\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0094it's breeding season".decodeBrokenJSON()!)
// Be careful—it's breeding season

print("\\u00c4\\u00b0zmir éûò€".decodeBrokenJSON()!)
// İzmir éûò€
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly with multibyte unicode JSON data. However as soon as the source string (`strbad` in your compressed example) already contains decoded special characters (e.g. éûò...), the UTF8 encode fails. Is it possible to adapt your code in order to make it digest these characters as well without failing?

Comment: @geohei: Yes, this is a workaround for a specific problem with wrongly encoded JSON from xkcd. Does your input suffer from the same problem? Can you show an example which needs to be “fixed”? It is not too complicated to write a more robust version of the above code (and in fact I have already prepared something). But before I post that here it would be good to see a concrete example of your input.

Comment: The situation is actually a bit different. I take data from a (locally stored) database. This database holds unicode, which will be (simplified speaking) imported by my app after JSON encoding. I can change the database manually towards correct encoding, but had quite some struggle without success. E.g. `\\u00c4\\u00b0zmir` (database) decodes to isolatin1 `Ä°zmir`, which makes `İzmir` in UTF8. That's using your code! I didn't find any tool or online converter which makes out of `\\u00c4\\u00b0` -> `İ`. So I decided to leave the unicode untouched and do the conversion using your snippet.

Comment: @geohei: I have added something, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Perfect your addendum - many thanks! I will continue to use it until I have a solution on how to properly change the source data. Unless broken JSON code from online sources, I do have the possibility to change my source data, but I'm not sure how. What would I have to do with `\\u00c4\\u00b0` to avoid `decodeBrokenJSON()`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything built in, but I did manage to write this for you.

```
extension String {
    func range(nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<Index> {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)!
    }

    func nsRange(range: Range<Index>) -> NSRange {
        return NSRange(range, in: self)
    }

    var fullRange: Range<Index> {
        return startIndex..<endIndex
    }

    var fullNSRange: NSRange {
        return nsRange(range: fullRange)
    }

    subscript(nsRange: NSRange) -> Substring {
        return self[range(nsRange: nsRange)]
    }

    func convertingUnicodeCharacters() -> String {
        var string = self
        // Characters need to be replaced in groups in case of clusters
        let groupedRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})+")
        for match in groupedRegex.matches(in: string, range: string.fullNSRange).reversed() {
            let groupedHexValues = String(string[match.range])
            var characters = [Character]()
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})")
            for hexMatch in regex.matches(in: groupedHexValues, range: groupedHexValues.fullNSRange) {
                let hexString = groupedHexValues[Range(hexMatch.range(at: 1), in: string)!]
                if let hexValue = UInt32(hexString, radix: 16),
                    let scalar = UnicodeScalar(hexValue) {
                    characters.append(Character(scalar))
                }
            }
            string.replaceSubrange(Range(match.range, in: string)!, with: characters)
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

It basically looks for any `\u<1-8 digit hex>` values and converts them into scalars. Should be fairly straightforward...  I've tried to test it a fair but but not sure if it catches every edge case.

My playground testing code was simply:

```
let string = "Be careful\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0094-\\u1F496\\u65\\u301it's breeding season"
let expected = "Be careful\u{00e2}\u{0080}\u{0094}-\u{1f496}\u{65}\u{301}it's breeding season"
string.convertingUnicodeCharacters() == expected // true
```

Comment: Martin R's solution looks better than mine. Far simpler, tbh. But this was a fun challenge :)

Comment: Actually his code crashes using my test string above.