# Swift: how to properly decode unicode characters?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, decoding

I'd like to read a JSON file of some messages, encoded by facebook. For example, I am fetching:

```
"content": "J\u00e2\u0080\u0099ai des bi\u00c3\u00a8res \u00f0\u009f\u008d\u00bb"
```

The correctly decoded text would be:

```
"content": "J'ai des bières "
```

I have tried this:

```
if let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: path + "/json_messages.json", encoding: .utf8) {
    let data = content.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                if let messages = json["messages"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    messages.forEach { message in
                        // ... here I proceed the extracted json strings
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
 }
```

And here is the result:

```
Jâai des biÃ¨res ð»
```

I have no idea how to correctly decode this content. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The JSON seems to be already corrupted. For example, The escape sequence for è should be `\00e8`, not `\u00c3\u00a8`, which are the UTF8 bytes.

Comment: Looks like a similar issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52387450/1187415 – the workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388645/1187415 fixes your string as well (although is should be fixed on the server side).